# Pyomo: Abstract model creation about power distribution

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am a new Pyomo/Python user. In the process of learning pyomo, I need to solve some optimization problems.

I need to make a balance between the total generation and demand (800 MW).
 If I want to find the minimum value of 'Sum(a*p^2+b*p+c))'.And this is the mathematic model:[mathematics model of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRRZn.png)

How can I construct an abstract model that I can choose the value of a, b, c from the same row in the table below? If I set the 'sets' individually, then the value of abc will come from the different row which cannot satisfy the formula. And how do I set a random value between the Pmin and Pmax? Use two constraints to limit the value?
It really makes me confused.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

model = AbstractModel()
model.J = Set()
model.A = Param(model.J)
model.B = Param(model.J)
model.C = Param(model.J)
model.P_min = Param(model.J)
model.P_max= Param(model.J)
model.P = Var(model.J, domain=NonNegativeReals)


def obj_expression(model):
    return sum(model.A* model.P**2+model.B*model.P+model.C for j in model.J)
model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression, sense=minimize)

# Upper bounds rule
def upper_bounds_rule(model,j):
return model.P[j] <= model.P_max[j]

model.upper = Constraint(model.J,rule=upper_bounds_rule)

# Lower bounds rule
def lower_bounds_rule(model, j):
    return model.P[j] >= model.P_min[j]

model.lower = Constraint(model.J, rule=lower_bounds_rule)


def rule_eq1(model,j):
    return sum(model.P[j] >= 800;

model.eq1 = Constraint(model.J, rule=rule_eq1)


opt = SolverFactory('Ipopt')

instance = model.create_instance("E:/pycharm_project/PD/pd.dat")
results = opt.solve(instance)  # solves and updates instance



#data file
# Creating the set J:
set J := g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9 g10 ;

# Creating Parameters A, B, C, P_min, P_max:
param : A B C P_min P_max:=
g1   0.0148 12.1  82  80  200
g2   0.0289 12.6  49  120 320
g3   0.0135 13.2  100 50  150
g4   0.0127 13.9  105 250 520
g5   0.0261 13.5  72  80   280
g6   0.0212 15.4  29  50   150
g7   0.0382 14.0  32  30   120
g8   0.0393 13.5  40  30   110
g9   0.0396 15.0  25  20   80
g10  0.0510 14.3  15  20   60
;
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks!

Vivi

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have your model written out?

Also, if you already have your data (above) in a data frame, you should just put it directly into a Concrete Model.  No need for abstract.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Last time, you helped me correct my model(that transportation problem). What I have done is shown above. I need to learn the abstract model because I need to use large data files in later learning. I don't know how to choose the value of a, b, c from the same row in the table. And how do I set a random value between the Pmin and Pmax? Use two constraints to limit the value? It really makes me confused.

Comment: Oh come on.  :)  That is a pretty feeble attempt.  Lots of errors/missing indices/etc.  re-look at your problem.  How many indices do you need?  Not sure where you see a random number, but reading the dox on the `random` can probably help with that too.

Comment: Really sorry for this model. I will try to correct it. But how can I choose the value of a, b, c from the same row in the table?

Comment: Use the same index for all 3?

Comment: Ok.Thanks sir. I have changed the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should structure your .dat files in accordance with what is described in the Pyomo documentation [here](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_abstractmodels/data/datfiles.html).

I believe something like this would work for you for parameters A, B, C:

```
# Creating the set J:
set J := g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9 g10 ;

# Creating Parameters A, B, C:
param : A B C := 
g1   0.0148 12.1  82
g2   0.0289 12.6  49
g3   0.0135 13.2  100
g4   0.0127 13.9  105
g5   0.0261 13.5  72
g6   0.0212 15.4  29
g7   0.0382 14.0  32
g8   0.0393 13.5  40
g9   0.0396 15.0  25
g10  0.0510 14.3  15 
;
```

Now I am not sure about `Pmin` and `Pmax`, since in your model they seem to be 2-dimensional, while in your data, they seem to only be 1-dimensional. But generally, you can follow the instructions in the link above to create your .dat files.

As for your second question, I am not sure I understand you correctly, but you refer to the `P_min <= P <= P_max` constraint in the mathematical model description, correct?

Then, for the `P_min <= P` part you need to slightly change your current constraint:

```
def lower_bounds_rule(model, i, j): 
     return model.P[i,j] >= model.P_min[i,j] 

model.lower = Constraint(model.i,model.j,rule=lower_bounds_rule)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, sir! And do you know how to generate the number which greater than Pmin and smaller than Pmax?

Comment: If it was helpful, please feel free to accept the answer. I have now edited it to answer your second question too.

Comment: Thanks, sir. And I have changed the code above. I know it is not a good model. Please point out the errors inside. And not all the generators I need cause I want to find the optimal distribution of these generators. But how to set the constraints of this?

Comment: Your model looks ok to me and in accordance with the mathematical description that you have provided. You don’t need an additional constraint to select generators. This will be implicitly done since for some generators the `P` variable will be equal to zero meaning they won’t be running.

Comment: But this model can't run and get the best result...I don't know why....Could you help me with it?

Comment: You have many syntax errors in your code. That is why it is not running. Your objective function should be: `sum(model.A[j]* model.P[j]**2+model.B[j]*model.P[j]+model.C[j] for j in model.J)`. In the `rule_eq1` constraint function, you are missing the closing bracket of the sum. Such errors you should be able to solve on your own...

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I correct these errors, can this model run successfully and get results?

Comment: Hard to tell. Just make sure to read the Python error messages when they come. They are there for a reason...

Comment: It shows that  '_GeneralVarData' object is not iterable'. I don't know what is that means.

Comment: The error message should also specify in which line the error occurs etc. I am afraid I cannot help you further debug your code.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your help, sir. I will try to debug my code.